# How to conditionally change object property value in the better way then this solution in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

Based on condition I am changing object value like this. Is there better way to do bellow checking without duplicate parts?

```
if (this.selected.id === productId) {
            this.obj1 = {
              ...this.product,
              tags: this.selected.tags,
              imgs: product.imgs,
            }
          } else {
            this.obj1 = {
               ...this.product,
              tags: this.selected.tags,
              imgs: [],
            }
          }
```

How can be above solution be more optimized e.g. with ? operator with inline condition?
Or something like this:

`this.selected.id === productId ? imgs: product.imgs` else don't add this property and value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks better if you use inline [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and don't repeat the rest of the code:

```
this.obj1 = {
          ...this.product,
          tags: this.selected.tags,
          imgs: this.selected.id === productId ? product.imgs: [],
        }
```

EDIT:
In case you don't want to do anything when the condition isn't met:

```
this.obj1 = {
      ...this.product,
      tags: this.selected.tags
    }

if(this.selected.id === productId){
    this.obj1.imgs = product.imgs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering then what if the condition is based on both property and value? Will this work if I try to change it for the whole line lets say if it's equal then add product.imgs property with it's value else add undefined or something?

Comment: I've added small case in the bottom of the question

Comment: @Dave then you need to do it in another line (see my answer)